# Asking question regarding future

Tags: phrase-choice, future-time, aspect

I have a scenario in which I am asking someone "When she get the accommodation in university?" She said "She will get the accommodation when she will be 22."

Now I want to turn this into interrogative way. I ask to her

> 1. Will she get accommodation when she get 22?
> 2. Will she get accommodation when she turn to 22?

What's the better way of asking this and my way of presenting its interrogation is right?

Comment: Are you sure you mean *accommodation* and not *accommodations* or *a commendation*?

Comment: *Will she get (an/the) accommodation when she turns 22?* is the correct question or interrogative form.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say, you have an event (a moment in time) in the future.  Let's also say, you want to associate something with that moment.  Since a moment does not last (or we can presume that it does not), it *moves immediately* from the future to the past, in a blink of an eye, so to speak.

In other words, it's in the future now (she ***will turn*** 22 at some moment in the future), but right after that moment, her **turning 22** will become *past*, right?  And soon after that moment something else will happen (or will become obvious), and that you want to describe, like her *accommodation*.

So, to re-iterate, with respect to the *accommodation*, the moment will be in the past.  But now it's in the future.  So, when we speak of the *accommodation* ***and*** *the moment of her turning 22* together, the *turning 22* is "***past-in-future***".

To express "*past-in-future*" we use **present tense**:

> When she **turn*s* 22**, she **will get** her accommodation.

Here, "turns" is present tense, 3<sup>rd</sup> person singular that denotes "past-in-future" with respect to the main clause of the sentence.

To turn this into interrogative, you put the main clause first, then the subordinate clause:

> **Will** she **get** her accommodation when she **turns** 22?

---

The subtle differences in meanings can be recognized when instead of the auxiliary verb "**will**" the verb "**shall**" is used.  Compare:

> **Shall** she get her accommodation when she **turns** 22?

means to ask about **the legal status** of getting the accommodation.  The rules or university code or by-laws might state (literally) that "*no student **shall** get their accommodation until the age of 22*", for instance, which **mandates** certain order, certain behavior, certain relation between getting the accommodation and the student's age.  It can also be expressed in the negative, "*students **shall not** get accommodation until the age of 22*".  If for some reason the rules do not state the age, a question aimed to clarify the rule can be asked with the use of the same *auxiliary verb*:

> When **shall** she get her accommodation?
>   At what age **shall** she be eligible for accommodation?

In normal circumstances we rarely use "*shall*" to refer to the future, unless we are certain or we are asking permission of (or making a suggestion to) somebody *in charge*:

> **Shall** I boil the water now, *master*?  -- Yes, Johnson, please do!
>   Are you ready, darling?  **Shall** we try for the next train?

Comment: So we use first form with Will or Shall ?

Comment: I'll edit my response in.

Comment: Could whoever downvoted my answer please give an explanation?

Comment: It wasn't me, but I think your analysis with the past-in-future is off. I think time phrases (conditionals "when", "after", "before") simply don't allow for future tenses. I'm not 100% sure why.

Comment: One reason might be that the present tense sometimes actually talks about the future. "I go back to school next Monday", "I turn 21 in April", "Tonight, we feast". I personally consider the simple present tense to be the "non past" tense.